# CUDA reduction-sum sample: data racing?

Tags: c++, cuda

I am new to CUDA and at the moment I'm investigating sum-reduction sample, which is relevant for my final goal.

The provided documentation describes how the kernel is optimized to quickly reduce a large array across blocks. The host function `reduce` in reduction_kernel.cu uses templates to optimize various kernels at compile-time.

```
template <class T>
void reduce(int size, int threads, int blocks,
            int whichKernel, T *d_idata, T *d_odata)
{
    // 
    // Long list with switch statement to have all optimized functions at compile-time
    //

    // amongst which (for instance):
    case 32:
        reduce5<T,  32><<< dimGrid, dimBlock, smemSize >>>(d_idata, d_odata, size);
        break;
```

EDIT: The kernel `reduce5` fills up `d_odata` with the partial sums of `d_idata`. more specifically, it sums the elements of `g_idata` with indices `2*blockSize*blockIdx.x` up to `2*blockSize*(blockIdx.x + 1)` (not inclusive) and stores the result in `g_odata[blockIdx.x]`. (EDIT-END)

The total sum is obtained by reducing across blocks until one block is left. The host code is used to synchronize kernels across 'levels' by repeatedly launching the kernel on the reduced array. The relevant bits of code in reduction.cpp:

```
template <class T>
T benchmarkReduce(int n, numThreads, numBlocks, /* more args */, 
                  T *h_odata, T *d_idata, T *d_odata) {

    // first kernel launch
    reduce<T>(n, numThreads, numBlocks, whichKernel, d_idata, d_odata);

    // repeated kernel launches
    int s=numBlocks;
    int kernel = whichKernel;

    while (s > cpuFinalThreshold)
    {   
        int threads = 0, blocks = 0;
        getNumBlocksAndThreads(kernel, s, maxBlocks, maxThreads, blocks, threads);

        reduce<T>(s, threads, blocks, kernel, d_odata, d_odata);

        if (kernel < 3) 
            s = (s + threads - 1) / threads;
        else
            s = (s + (threads*2-1)) / (threads*2);  
    }
}
```

I am happy with the first kernel call, which stores the partial sums of `d_idata` in `d_odata`. My worries arise for the **second kernel launch** (inside the while loop): Namely, the kernel will **both read and write to `d_odata`**, which could lead to data racing.
For instance, the second block could write its partial sum to `d_odata[1]` before the first block has read its original value; which is required for the partial sum of the first block.

Am I missing a detail?

Comment: It depends on the implementation of the reduction kernel, which you haven't provided. It is possible to do an in-place reduction without data races.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but it does not happen in the sample code. For instance, `reduce5` (which is wrapped by `reduce`) reads `d_idata[blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + threadIdx.x]` and `d_idata[blockIdx.x*(blockSize*2) + threadIdx.x + blockSize]` and stores in `d_odata[blockIdx.x]`.

Comment: The code being discussed is the [cuda sample reduction code](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#cuda-parallel-reduction).  OP did not indicate this clearly.

Comment: I believe this is a potential race condition.  I don't think you are missing any details.  It's not observed to cause a problem in practice because: 1. for some of the selected reduction kernels, only 1 block will be launched at this point. 2. For some other configurations, all the blocks at this point can be scheduled simultaneously, on some GPUs, 3. the default block scheduling order tends to schedule lower-numbered `blockIdx.x` before higher numbered `blockIdx.x`  I have filed a bug with NVIDIA to investigate and possibly improve the code.  I don't have any further details at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the CUDA 8.0 package.  CUDA 8.0 should be available soon.